# React Native Component Mount Issue while Navigating

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

Hello I am Working in react native and getting the following error while navigating

Error :

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method Error

These are the code of the following Classes
Main `index.js class`
[index.js Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vFHc.png)

Splash Screen code[Splash Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3i0.png)

Login Screen Code
[Login Screen Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7QeR.png)

Errors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIheZ.png)

Comment: Firstly try to add code snippets here instead of images if possible. To answer your question I see 2 componentWillUnmount() calls in your SplashScreen code. Please modify that

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at this article: [https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7#:~:text=Warning%3A%20Can't%20perform%20a,tasks%20in%20the%20componentWillUnmount%20method.&text=in%20your%20application.-,To%20fix%2C%20cancel%20all%20subscriptions%20and%20asynchronous,in%20a%20useEffect%20cleanup%20function](https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7#:%7E:text=Warning%3A%20Can%27t%20perform%20a,tasks%20in%20the%20componentWillUnmount%20method.&text=in%20your%20application.-,To%20fix%2C%20cancel%20all%20subscriptions%20and%20asynchronous,in%20a%20useEffect%20cleanup%20function).

and also this from github:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/434

Comment: Rather than sharing links directly as your answer, you need to explain it here. If you have such links that can help your answer understood then share those in the comment section. You've got an upvote from me so that you can keep moving with great answering.